# Using 'GoogleMaps' and 'GooglePlaces' pods, when archiving iOS build receive error for multiple commands produce GoogleUtilities target

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode10

Having trouble archiving - I receive a Build System Information error that says

```
Multiple commands produce '.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':
1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-ac14cd06' has create directory command with output '.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

I recently updated to the latest version of Xcode (v 10.0). I am also using Cocoapod version 1.6.0.beta.1

Using GoogleMaps pod version 2.7.0, GooglePlaces pod version 2.7.0
When I run 'pod install' it also installs 'GoogleUtilities (5.3.0)'.

I tried deleting my Podlock, Podfile, .xcworkspace, etc and starting over with a new Podfile, pod init, pod install, etc. after updating Cocoapods but still no luck.

I'm looking for a duplicate relating to GoogleUtilities or Places or Maps in Build Phases within Embed Pod Frameworks, but not having much luck. When I look inside the Pods folder, I do see two GoogleUtilities frameworks, "GoogleUtilities-00567490" and "GoogleUtilities-ac14cd06", but both appear not to have the exact same contents.

Only now experiencing this issue after updating Xcode to version 10.0.

Comment: What's in the Podfile?

Comment: This is not because of 'GoogleMaps' and 'GooglePlaces'. You can remove GoogleMaps because GooglePlaces installs it anyway.
The issue is that you have multiple targets in your project and you're using 'GooglePlaces' (or 'Firebase' or any other pod that is dependent on GoogleUtilities) in both the targets. Seems like some issue with the new build system, while archiving it copies the frameworks generated from pods of all the targets. That's why Legacy build system is working.

Comment: @abhinavroy23 Yes, I do have multiple targets in my project as I have a target for the development app, the production app, and testing targets. Thanks for the tip about removing Google Maps. Definitely using Firebase as well. Hope the issue with the new build system is resolved or perhaps there's a way I can better order my Podfile

Comment: My pleasure @Brown Did you use the Legacy build system to resolve this? I am facing a similar issue and looking for other workarounds as well, Please let me know if you find something.

Comment: @abhinavroy23 Yes, I used the Legacy Built system as a workaround. I don't know of any other solutions at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to File > Workspace Settings and then changing the Build System from "New Build System (Default)" to "Legacy Build System" will allow you to archive for now. Hopefully, another solution comes along for using those pods and the new build system in Xcode 10.0

Answer (score 3):

For me, the same issue was coming and Most of the people saying to change the build system to legacy, but when I tried its It started swift compilers error. resolved as mentioned below.

1. Go to your **target** and click on (**your_app_name_target**).
2. Select **Build Phases**.
3. Expand **Copy Pods Resources**.
4. See the section **Output Files**.
5. This section should be empty. **Remove any entry there**.
6. **Rebuild** your Project.